# Как получить лист разделенных запятыми значений колонки, если длина превышает 4000? ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: sql, oracle

Eсть запрос, который использует функцию `LISTAGG`, чтобы получить значения колонки в виде разделенной запятыми строки.

Вот воспроизводимый пример запроса, который работает:

```
create table t1 (code) as
    select 'code'||to_char (rownum, 'fm09999')||rpad (' ', 22, 'X')  
    from dual connect by level<=1024
/
col list for a32 wrap
select listagg (code, ',') within group (order by code) "List"
from t1
where rownum <= 10
/

List
--------------------------------
code00001 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
code00002 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
[...]
code00010 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Но если записей в группе много, то получим исключение:

> ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Проблема в том, что конкатенация строк не может превышать длину 4000 символов.

Можно попробовать обрезать результат:

```
select substr (listagg (code, ',') within group (order by code), 1, 3994)||'[more]' "List"
from t1
where rownum <= 128
/
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

Но так тоже не работает, потому что исключение возникает до того, как `SUBSTR` будет вызвана.

Как можно решить проблему?

Допустимо с усечением до первых 4000 символов, включая указатель, что лист неполный.
В идеале, конечно, полный лист, но ведь `LISTAGG` не может работать с `CLOB`.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/28301443

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/29776035

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/13795220

Answer (score 3):

В 12.2 и выше, с опцией [ON OVERFLOW](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466):

```
select listagg (code, ',' on overflow truncate '[more]') within group (order by code) "List"
from t1
where rownum <= 128
/

List
--------------------------------
code00001 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
code00002 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
[...]
code00123 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
[more](5)
```

---

В более ранних версиях, возможно в подзапросе подсчитать аналитической функцией накапливающуюся сумму длины агрегирования, и при превышении лимита, больше не конкантенировать последующие значения.

Например, так:

```
with params (delimiter, moreavail, delimlen, maxlen) as (
    select q.*, length (delimiter), 4000-length (moreavail)
    from (select ',' delimiter, ',[more]' moreavail from dual) q
), subq as (
    select totallen, maxlen, moreavail, 
        listagg (code, delimiter) within group (order by code) list
    from (
        select code, par.*, 
            sum (length (code) + par.delimlen) over (order by code) runninglen,
            sum (length (code) + par.delimlen) over () totallen
        from t1, params par
        order by code)
    where runninglen < maxlen 
    group by totallen, delimiter, maxlen, moreavail
)
select
    case when totallen > maxlen then list||moreavail
    else list end "List"
from subq
/

List
-------------------------------------
code00001 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
code00002 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
[...]
code00124 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
[more]
```

Answer (score 3):

Довольно простой способ, воспользоваться функцией [XMLAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLAGG.html#GUID-BCD1D755-5E26-4F73-BA22-521C30D275DA):

```
set long 1000000 pages 2000
select rtrim (
    xmlAgg (xmlElement (e, code, ',').extract ('//text()') order by code).getClobVal (), 
        ',') "List"
from t1
/
```

Вернёт `CLOB`, поэтому никаких ограничений нет:

```
List
--------------------------------
code00001 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
code00002 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
[...]
code01024 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 3):

Если другие решения по каким-то причинам не подходят, то реализуйте свою функцию используя [ODCI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/addci/using-user-defined-aggregate-functions.html#GUID-D7E77319-DC23-4CF0-B746-27ED7BE9240D) (*Oracle Data Cartrige Interface*).

Пример вызова такой функции:

```
select longListAgg (code, ';') "List"
from t1
order by code
/

List
--------------------------------
code00001 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
code00002 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
[...]
code01023 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
code01024 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Реализация функции ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a92a2e686d44d11d4ec864b64cad1d07)):

```
create or replace type listAggType as object (
    vals clob,
    delm varchar2 (8),
    static function ODCIAggregateInitialize (
        ctx in out listAggType, delm varchar2) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateIterate (
        self in out listAggType, value in varchar2) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateTerminate (
        self listAggType, returnValue out clob, flags number) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateMerge (
        self in out listAggType, ctx2 in listAggType) return number);
/
```

```
create or replace type body listAggType is
    static function ODCIAggregateInitialize (
        ctx in out listAggType, delm varchar2) return number is
    begin
        ctx := listAggType (null, delm);
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;
    member function ODCIAggregateIterate (
        self in out listAggType, value varchar2) return number is
    begin
        self.vals := self.vals||value||delm;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;
    member function ODCIAggregateTerminate (
        self listAggType, returnValue out clob, flags number) return number is
    begin
        returnValue := rtrim (self.vals, delm);
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;
    member function ODCIAggregateMerge (
        self in out listAggType, ctx2 listAggType) return number is
    begin
        self.vals := self.vals||ctx2.vals;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;
end;
/
create or replace function longListAgg (
    val varchar2, delm varchar2 := ','
    ) return clob parallel_enable aggregate using listAggType;
/
```